# Create a new record with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table whose primary key id is an identity column. I think that when a new record is created, id will be incremented by 1.

However I found that it is 0 while debugging. Why?

The necessary code:

```
  public DbSet<testDetails> testDetailRecords { get; set; }
  testDetails test = testContext.testDetailRecords.Create();
  // test.id is 0 when hover over it
  public class testDetails : IEntityWithRelationships
  {
      [Key]
       [Required]
       [Display(Name = "Primary Key", Description = "Primary Key")]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public long id { get; set; }
```

Comment: After SubmitChanges is called the value is incremented.

Comment: Have you persisted the entity (i.e. have you attached it to the context and called `SaveChanges`)?

Comment: Are you checking before or after calling `SaveChanges` on `DbContext`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The record is not created until you commit it with a `SaveChanges()`.

Answer (score 5):

It is 0 because it is not created yet.

```
        TestContext context = new TestContext();

        var increment = context.IncrementTest.Create();
        increment.name = "testbyme";

        context.IncrementTest.Add(increment);


        context.SaveChanges();
```

That works without throwing any exceptions for me.

Answer (score 1):

> I think that when a new record is created, id will be incremented by 1.

Who does that? The DBMS. Where does the record currently live? Only in your application.

Call `testContext.SaveChanges()` to insert the record in the database, after which the entity's `id` property will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

`SaveChanges()` returns the number of rows affected. If it returns `0`, then nothing has been saved. To check if the item has been saved:

```
int rowsAffected = context.SaveChanges();
if (rowsAffected > 0)
   Console.WriteLine("Saved!");
else
   Console.WriteLine("Nothing saved! Check error using try catch");
```